# Показ блока определенное число раз

Tags: jquery

При заходе на страницу пользователю должен показывать блок с выбором категории инфы.

Блок должен показываться определенное число раз, допустим 3. Т.е. человек трижды заходя на страницу видит этот блок, а уже при четвертом возвращении подразумевается что он помнит об его существовании и блок показываться не должен, но его можно вызвать.

Как это можно реализовать? пример arxip.ru
там при заходе в категорию выбор подкатегорий показывается только 3 раза, и вот я никак не могу понять как это сделано.

думается мне что это делается на jquery, но понять как не могу.

Answer (score 2):

Лучшим вариантом будет использовать Local Storage для сохранения количества показов.

Comment: Local Storage только в HTML 5, а значит далеко не во всех браузерах работает

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать плагин для работы с cookies. Скачать его можно [здесь](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
При каждом просмотре увеличивать счётчик просмотров, который будет хранится в cookies пользователя. При значении равном 3, необходимо скрывать нужный блок

Comment: Зачем плагин, если можно обойтись и **Local Storage**?

Comment: @Deonis солидарен

Comment: Господи везде плагины!Скоро все будет в плагинах.